# Intellij Idea - Spring Boot Application fails on starting a Debug session

Tags: maven, debugging, spring-boot, intellij-idea, java-9

I have a Spring Boot application which runs successfully and throws no error or whatsoever while at runtime.

```
$ mvn spring-boot:run
```

However when I attempt to start debug with default configurations, it is throwing me an error;

```
--
Information: java: Errors occurred while compiling module ...
Information: javac 9.0.1 was used to compile java sources
Information: compilation completed with 1 error and 0 warnings
java:Illegal char <*> at index 7: ../lib/*.jar 
--
```

If It is mentioning about index.html file; here its line 7:

```
<div th:if="${!projects.isEmpty()}" th:remove="tag">
```

[Here](https://paste.ee/p/gSQ0k) is maven dependency tree

[Here](http://paste.ee/p/GS0zD) is pom.xml file

Comment: Can you share your pom.xml too

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reminder. 

(I had to exclude jetty:servlet-api dependency from SOAPUI's API since it was conflicting with servlet being used with Spring (~3.x I guess.))

Comment: Problem has been resolved by changing the jdk to version 1.8